# Error C2504 - Base class undefined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I have a rather simple problem

This is my `firstcluster.h`

```
#pragma once

#include "cluster.h"

class FirstCluster:public Cluster{
    ...

public:
    ...
};
```

Code for cluster.h:

```
#pragma once

// File: cluster.h

class Cluster {
protected:
    ...

public:
    ...
};
```

And i'm getting the error:

```
error C2504: 'Cluster' : base class undefined
```

Sometimes i get this IntelliSense error:

```
IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed ... Line 10 Column 27
```

But it doesn't always come up.

The `cluster.h` is included, as you can see, and all other header files are protected with `#pragma once`

I really don't know what could go wrong here?

Can circular include make problems even if i protected everything with `#pragma once`?
I'm using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Show the code for cluster

Comment: I updated the first post with code of cluster.h

Comment: Yes circular include problems will still occur even with #pragma once and or include guards. However you would have to include FirstCluster.h in cluster.h to create a circular include in this case. Are you doing that and if so why?

Comment: Is that the only error you get? Make sure to post all the errors sorted by the first one.

Comment: It was a circular include after all. I managed to solve the problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I got this due to circular include.

I included all my headers in "include.h" and include it in everywhere else.

I managed to avoid circular include by just including standard headers in include.h.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the exact same problem, adding

```
#ifndef CLUSTER_H
#define CLUSTER_H

/* your code */

#endif
```

helped to solve the problem. the ifndef part is obviously for include duplications but "define", i think, did help.

Answer (score 2):

This code looks normal, so:
if cluster.h actually defines Cluster class, then check for missing namespace around Cluster (if you use a namespace), upper-lower case usage in 'Cluster' vs 'cluster', 'cLuster', etc., also check that the Cluster definition is not local to another class.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I added the code for cluster.h

I'm not using namespaces and i was unable to find any upper-lower inconsistencies o.O

Comment: If you isolate these 2 .h and 2 .cpp files and try to compile them do they work? Also, try using #ifndef _Cluster_H_/#define _Cluster_H_/.../#endif<empty line>  around the headers instead of #pragma once. Never had problems with MS-specific #pragma once, but I prefer using the #ifndef ... version of header single inclusion.

Comment: I tried with #ifndef but it's not working.

Also, sometimes i get this IntelliSense error:   IntelliSense: incomplete type is not allowed ... Line 10 Column 27

But it doesn't always come up.

Comment: It was a circular include after all.
I managed to solve the problem, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs due to circular include so We can handle this by adding the header of child class in the bottom of the parent class